# 19.10: No headphone sound

Tags: sound, 19.10

Computer (laptop): [Dell Studio 1749](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/studio-1749/overview)

Recent install of Ubuntu 19.10

Problem: No audio through headphones
Audio only works through laptop speakers

I have tried changing settings in alsamixer, which lists `HDA Intel MDA` as the sound card. lspci lists `Intel 5 series` with no MDI, PSC or other designation.

I tried reinstalling alsa-pulseaudio like many other posts here suggested, but this had no effect.

The audio works as expected in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I now have my headphones working in Ubuntu 19.10.  This issue was answered 7 years ago right here on AskUbuntu at [3.5 audio jack issue doesn't work on a Dell Studio 1749](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141865/3-5-audio-jack-issue-doesnt-work-on-a-dell-studio-1749).

To resolve the issue, you have to add a line to the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file to specify the sound card and laptop model. In my case, the line is 'options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6-dmic.

Thanks all.